# Conditionally replacing column values in pandas with values from a different dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, replace, lookup

I have two csv's which, when read as dataframes, look something like this:

```
df:

   TargetIndex Current1 Current2 Current3
0            0       'D'      'D'      'G'
1            2        0       'E'      'F'
2            0       'A'      'E'      'F'
3            1        0        0        0
4            0       'A'       0       'A'
5            3       'G'       0        0
6            2       'F'      'E'       0
7            4        0        0        0


df2:

    TargetIndex Target1 Target2 Target3
0             1      'A'     'A'     'A'
1             2      'B'     'B'     'B'
2             3      'C'     'C'     'C'
3             4      'A'     'B'     'C'
```

What I'm trying to do is replace only the `0` values in the `Current` columns with the values in the `Target` columns. However, only on rows in which the `TargetIndex` value isn't `0`.

I'm admittedly quite inexperienced with Python and normally I'd use a combination of additional columns and the LOOKUP function in excel for this, so I'm struggling quite a bit.

What I've done so far is read a bunch of threads here, and tried various uses of `.loc`, `.isin`, `.replace`, and `.map` among other things but I've found it very hard to apply the conditions of `TargetIndex != 0` and `CurrentX == 0`.

Another thing I'm finding difficult is using the second dataframe in the first place, I've tried making it into a `.dict`with such limited success that I do know how it works somewhat, I can't quite apply it.

I did manage to reverse engineer the desired outcome into the following spaghetti code:

```
df['Target1'] = df['TargetIndex'].map(df2.set_index('TargetIndex')['Target1'])
df['Target2'] = df['TargetIndex'].map(df2.set_index('TargetIndex')['Target2'])
df['Target3'] = df['TargetIndex'].map(df2.set_index('TargetIndex')['Target3'])
S1 = df.Current1 == 0
S2 = df.Current2 == 0
S3 = df.Current3 == 0
df.loc[S1, 'Current1'] = df['TargetIndex']
df.loc[S2, 'Current2'] = df['TargetIndex']
df.loc[S3, 'Current3'] = df['TargetIndex']
df.replace({'Current1': { 1 : 'A', 2 : 'B', 3 : 'C', 4 : 'A'}}, inplace=True)
df.replace({'Current2': { 1 : 'A', 2 : 'B', 3 : 'C', 4 : 'B'}}, inplace=True)
df.replace({'Current3': { 1 : 'A', 2 : 'B', 3 : 'C', 4 : 'C'}}, inplace=True)
df.drop(df.columns[[4, 5, 6]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Which does indeed produce the desired outcome:

```
df:

   TargetIndex Current1 Current2 Current3
0            0       'D'      'D'      'G'
1            2       'B'      'E'      'F'
2            0       'A'      'E'      'F'
3            1       'A'      'A'      'A'
4            0       'A'       0       'A'
5            3       'G'      'C'      'C'
6            2       'F'      'E'      'B'
7            4       'A'      'B'      'C'
```

However it requires manually typing out what to replace what with, which isn't quite efficient or viable when the df2 csv contains 5000+ rows.
There has to be a much better way to do this which I'm just not seeing or understanding properly, so I figured I might as well ask.

Comment: Are the zeros in the last 3 columns strings or integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use if same number of columns:

```
#create index with 
df1 = df1.set_index('TargetIndex')
df2 = df2.set_index('TargetIndex')
#set same columns names for align data
df2.columns = df1.columns

#replace 0 with NaNs and replace NaNs by df2
df = df1.mask(df1 == 0).combine_first(df2)
print (df)
            Current1 Current2 Current3
TargetIndex                           
0                'D'      'D'      'G'
0                'A'      'E'      'F'
0                'A'      NaN      'A'
1                'A'      'A'      'A'
2                'B'      'E'      'F'
2                'F'      'E'      'B'
3                'G'      'C'      'C'
4                'A'      'B'      'C'
```

If order is important add `reset_index` for sorting:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index().set_index('TargetIndex')
df2 = df2.set_index('TargetIndex')
df2.columns = df1.columns[1:]

df = (df1.mask(df1 == 0)
        .combine_first(df2)
        .sort_values('index')
        .drop('index', 1)
        .reset_index()
        .fillna(0))
print (df)
   TargetIndex Current1 Current2 Current3
0            0      'D'      'D'      'G'
1            2      'B'      'E'      'F'
2            0      'A'      'E'      'F'
3            1      'A'      'A'      'A'
4            0      'A'        0      'A'
5            3      'G'      'C'      'C'
6            2      'F'      'E'      'B'
7            4      'A'      'B'      'C'
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves my issue!
That was really fast too!